# EXTJS 3.4 HOW TO GET RECORD DATAVIEW ON selectionchange

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

How to get the record on [selection change](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.DataView-event-selectionchange) when using [Ext.DataView](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.DataView) ?

I would like to get value 'IdPrd' in the selectionchange event function.

```
var tpl_ram = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<ul>',
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<li class="phone">',
                '<img width="64" height="64" src="data/catalogo/ramos/imagenes/{IdRm}/{IdRm}.jpg" />',
                '<strong>{NomRm}</strong>',
                '<span>{DescRm}</span>',
            '</li>',
        '</tpl>',
    '</ul>');

var ramos_dw = new Ext.DataView({
    tpl: tpl_ram,
    store: ramos_productos,
    id: 'ramos_dw',
    itemSelector: 'li.phone',
    overClass: 'phone-hover',
    singleSelect: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    emptyText: 'SIN RESULTADOS QUE MOSTRAR',
    listeners: {
        'click': function() {},
         selectionchange: {
            fn: function(dv, nodes) {
                //i want on selection get value 'IdPrd'
                var record = nodes[0];
                console.log("advert id - " + record.get('IdPrd'))
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how your model from your store looks like. But solution would be to get the data object first.

So the code would be:

```
var recordData = nodes[0].getData();
// keep in mind that user can select more than 1 node --> nodes[0] 
console.log("advert id - " + recordData['IdPrd'])
```

You can also simply put `debugger;` into your selectionchange function listener and explore how exactly the nodes object which you get in your specific example looks like.